Error running SSH Tunnel Container in Docker
I'm encountering an error while attempting to run an SSH tunnel container in Docker. The container exits, and I receive the following error message:
==== SSH keys ==========================================================
Adding all keys in $SSH_AGENT_KEYS environment variable to agent...
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/ssh/id_rsa' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored.

Environment

Docker version: 26.1.1

Docker Compose YAML
# SSH tunnel
image: hgdata1/ssh-tunnel:latest
networks:
  - xxx
ports:
  - "443:443"
environment:
  - TUNNEL_REMOTE_HOST=${xxxxx}
  - SSH_REMOTE_HOSTNAME=${xxxx}
  - SSH_REMOTE_USER=my.user
  - SSH_AGENT_KEYS=id_rsa_private_key
  - SSH_STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=no
volumes:
  - "~/.ssh:/ssh"


Additional Information

My machine has the private and public key pair, and it's exported to my shell.

container should not exit and establish a successful connection

Why are you setting SSH_STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=no?

i tried with setting  SSH_STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=yes and still the same problem

The error is clear: Permissions 0644 for '/ssh/id_rsa' are too open. You have to set the the permissions of your private key to 0600 or 0400. See this answer for the permissions of the other files/directories https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder
The SSH_STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING is referring to the public key of the server in your known-hosts file
